# Mocking __call__ attribute doesn't mock the function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I'm trying to mock a function in the following way:

```
def foo(x):
    return 10 * x

from unittest.mock import patch

with patch.object(foo, "__call__", lambda x: 100 * x):
    print(foo(5))
    print(foo.__call__(5))
```

However, the output is as follows:

```
50
500
```

instead of

```
500
500
```

That is, `foo(5)` doesn't use the mocked `__call__` attribute. I have assumed that function call like `foo(5)` is always converted to `foo.__call__(5)`. Apparently that is not the case, but I don't know why. Is it possible to mock the function with `patch.object`?

I know I could patch it with `patch("path.to.foo", lambda x: 100*x)` but I was hoping I could patch the object without needing to know the path. But perhaps I just need to do something like:

```
patch(foo.__module__+'.'+foo.__name__, lambda x: 100*x)
```

But I'm not sure if this is a good way of patching. To me, this looks like asking for trouble, but I'm not sure what that trouble could be.

So, how can I patch a function object?

Comment: I don't know what is going on here, but I know for sure that things are [not always looked up as your naive intuition would think](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup) and then monkey patching can become a nightmare. Then there is the problem of where to patch that you already noticed. Even if you get it right things break when you reorganize your code. I can only suggest you not to patch. There must be a better way of solving [whatever problem you are trying to solve](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: Indeed, `foo(5)` is converted to `type(foo).__call__(foo, 5)`. Also, the link to the X-Y problem is a very good point. So, what I'm actually trying to achieve: I have some functions that have side effects (e.g., read files, query database). In unit tests, I want to replace some of these functions with pure mocked functions for simplicity, then the other functions that call these side-effectful functions can be tested in a pure way. It's probably not a perfect design, but given the current codebase, this seemed like the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

`foo(5)` converts to `type(foo).__call__(foo, 5)` instead of `foo.__call__(5)`.

So, one needs to modify the `__call__` method of the class, not the instance. In order to not mess with other instances of the same class, the instance should be created from a unique class, then one can patch the class freely.

I couldn't find a way to change the class of a function object, so I created a simple wrapper for functions, that converts the function into an instance of a unique class while still behaving similarly as the original function. Then, it's possible to patch the `__call__` method of that class:

```
from unittest import mock

def mockable_function(f):

    class Function():

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return Function()

@mockable_function
def foo(x):
    return 10 * x

with mock.patch.object(type(foo), "__call__", lambda _, x: 100 * x):
    print(foo(5))
    print(foo.__call__(5))
```

This outputs:

```
500
500
```

Perhaps not very pretty, but at least one way of writing functions that can be modified with `mock.patch.object`.

Based on my tests, the problem with using `mock.patch("some.module.foo", ...)` is that if some modules have imported `foo` as `from some.module import foo`, that `foo` won't be affected, whereas with `mock.patch.object(foo, ...)` it is correctly patched.